# Quartz triggers disappeared - minute cron vs minute interval

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am facing the problem of disappearing triggers from database (jobs are still persisted but they are not trigger without triggers) and I have now idea what is deleting them..

I have quartz 2.3.0 cron expression for every minute:

> 0 0/1 0/1 1/1 * ? *

I wonder if it would be better to have interval simple trigger instead of cron trigger. Job can process data for a few minutes so it will always miss some minutes but what configuration would be better in this case - cron expression or one minute interval ?

```
<bean id="myJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="mypackage.MyJob" />
        <property name="durability" value="true" />
        <property name="requestsRecovery" value="true" />
    </bean>
```